# Data Restore For a particular client

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a requirement in java that the Client should be able to revert back to any version of data in mysql database.

ie The client should be able to restore previous data.

How can i implement the restore functionality?

We have a single database to store all clients data. So the complete data base backup and restore will not work, because it will restore data for other clients as well.

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: you can mark the problem as solved by accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could store the date in the table that you wanna backup (lets say a document change), and each time add a new version of the edited document. The the user can choose the date that will be used to restore the document to the state it had in that date! So actually you are going to give him the old document saved in that date.